# Starting with Haskell

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain to me whats going on in this function?

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

I do understand what curried functions are, this could be re-written like this:

```
applyTwice :: ((a -> a) -> (a -> (a)))
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

However I dont fully understand the `(+3)` operator and how it works. Maybe it's something really stupid but I can't figure it out. 
Can someone explain step by step how the function works? Thanks =)

```
applyTwice :: ((a -> a) -> (a -> (a)))
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell has "operator slicing":  if you omit one or both of the arguments to an operator, Haskell automatically turns it into a function for you.

Specifically, `(+3)` is missing the first argument (Haskell has no unary `+`).  So, Haskell makes that expression into a function that takes the missing argument, and returns the input value plus 3:

```
-- all the following functions are the same
f1 x = x + 3
f2 = (+3)
f3 = \ x -> x + 3
```

Similarly, if you omit both arguments, Haskell turns it into a function with two (curried) arguments:

```
-- all the following functions are the same
g1 x y = x + y
g2 = (+)
g3 = \ x y -> x + y
```

From comments:  note that Haskell *does* have unary `-`.  So, `(-n)` is not an operator slice, it just evaluates the negative (same as `negate n`).

If you want to slice binary `-` the way you do `+`, you can use `(subtract n)` instead:

```
-- all the following functions are the same
h1 x = x - 3
h2 = subtract 3
h3 = \ x -> x - 3
```

Comment: So, for example, `(+3)` is the same as `(\x -> x + 3)`.

Comment: Added a lambda version to my examples

Comment: One could ad for a newbie that there is one and only one exception to the rule: `(-n)` is not a section, but the sme as `negate n`

Comment: added a section on `(-n)` and `subtract`

Comment: `subtract` is quite a long word that I am too lazy to type. I generally just write `(+(-x))`

Comment: I sometimes wish I could make arbitrary expressions infix, which would allow ``(`(-)` n)``.